# Creating good kable output in RStudio

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I've got a data frame that looks like this:

```
er.frame <- structure(c(0.475, 0.525, 0.45, 0.475, 0.45, 0.55, 0.425, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.45, 0.375, 0.55, 0.425, 0.5, 0.475, 0.4, 0.45, 0.375, 
0.55, 0.425), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("CSP.LDA.error.rate", 
"CSP.SWLDA.error.rate", "CSP.SVM.error.rate")))

kable(er.frame)

|  CSP.LDA.error.rate|  CSP.SWLDA.error.rate|  CSP.SVM.error.rate|
|-------------------:|---------------------:|-------------------:|
|               0.475|                 0.500|               0.500|
|               0.525|                 0.500|               0.475|
|               0.450|                 0.400|               0.400|
|               0.475|                 0.450|               0.450|
|               0.450|                 0.375|               0.375|
|               0.550|                 0.550|               0.550|
|               0.425|                 0.425|               0.425|
```

I'd like to have that `kable` output be processed by `knitr` and make a nice table in the HTML report. Following the documentation in `?kable`, I made this snippet:

````
``` {r snippet}
opts_chunk$set(results='asis')
kable(er.frame)
```
````

My HTML report, though, as generated by RStudio, is just the echoed console output (or nothing at all, if I add the option `output=FALSE`):

```
## |  CSP.LDA.error.rate|  CSP.SWLDA.error.rate|  CSP.SVM.error.rate|
## |-------------------:|---------------------:|-------------------:|
## |               0.425|                 0.400|               0.400|
## |               0.425|                 0.475|               0.500|
## |               0.400|                 0.400|               0.400|
## |               0.425|                 0.425|               0.425|
## |               0.425|                 0.325|               0.275|
## |               0.350|                 0.375|               0.375|
## |               0.450|                 0.425|               0.425|
```

The above is also what appears in the generated Markdown file with accompanying ```` ``` ```` delimiters, and it looks just fine if I remove the delimiters and the hashes.

How do I properly output using `kable`? [This question's accepted answer hints at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488350/programmatically-creating-markdown-tables-in-r-with-knitr), but doesn't go as far as the documentation.

Incidentally, I'm running R 2.15.1, knitr 1.5.15.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`opts_chunk$set` and `opts_current$set` don't affect the chunk in which they are called.

from `?opts_chunk`

> Note the global options set in one chunk will not affect the options in this chunk itself, and that is why we often need to set global options in a separate chunk.

The following option will work:

````
```{r, results = 'asis'}
kable(er.frame)
```
````