# How to view a list like table style in r

Tags: r, list, datatable, formatting, r-markdown

I am facing an issue as how to presenting data in a list as table (data frame) format, in the list each element as a character vector, and these vectors may have different length, the example list as below:

```
sample_list <- list("Matched x" = c("Ella", "Mila"), "Unmatched x" = c("Isla"), "Matched y" = c(), "Unmatched y" = c("Emma", "Olivia"))
sample_list
```

Normally, if you use `str(sample_list)`, it will print as below:

```
> str(sample_list)
List of 4
 $ Matched x  : chr [1:2] "Ella" "Mila"
 $ Unmatched x: chr "Isla"
 $ Matched y  : NULL
 $ Unmatched y: chr [1:2] "Emma" "Olivia"
```

Is there a way to show the result on `R markdown` (`.Rmd` file) generated file (e.g `.html` / `.pdf`) as below (**no need strictly same but like table style**) ?
[image]

Comment: Relevant discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488350/programmatically-creating-markdown-tables-in-r-with-knitr

Comment: Hi, thelatemail, let me check there, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main issue is to get data in the required format to display table. You can include the following in R-markdown document.

```
sample_list <- list("Matched x" = c("Ella", "Mila"), "Unmatched x" = c("Isla"), 
               "Matched y" = c(), "Unmatched y" = c("Emma", "Olivia"))

max_len <- max(lengths(sample_list))
df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, c(lapply(sample_list, function(x) 
               c(x, rep('', max_len - length(x)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
knitr::kable(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Tested, correct solution and to uniform vector length with empty string to fill in is great, vote up !

Comment: Variation - `data.frame(lapply(sample_list, function(x) c(x, rep('', max_len - length(x)))), check.names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse-friendly version:

```
library(dplyr)

max_len <- max(lengths(sample_list))

df <- purrr::map_df(sample_list, ~ c(., rep('', max_len - length(.))))

df %>% 
  flextable::flextable() %>% 
  flextable::autofit()
```

[image: flextable_of_df_from_list]